# How can I resolve a Network Error while sending data from input fields to my backend in React Native with Expo Go and Express js?

Tags: react-native, express, localhost, expo-go, general-network-error

I am experiencing Network Error while trying to send data from input fields to my backend.
I am running frontend of my app on Expo Go. Expo Go and my computer are connected to the same wifi. Everything is working great till I am trying to send data to my backend. I am running Express js on  localhost http://localhost:3000/. Expo Go, on my mobile, is using exp://192.168.2.129:19000. No data is being sent to the backend.
I'm working on Mac, my firewall is OFF. Expo Go runs on Iphone, iOS 16.2 fabric settings...

I moved all the backend to https://replit.com/, platform for developers and everything is working fine again, data being received.

My question is: is it possible to not use external platforms and just run frontend and backend from my computer, on my localhost?

thank you for help, Eva

Comment: Give  us other details of your environmnet. Firewalls? Windows? Linux?

Comment: Thx for reply. I'm working on Mac, my firewall is OFF. Expo Go runs on Iphone, iOS 16.2 fabric settings...  Don't know if thats useful, but I copied this from my terminal: TMPDIR=/var/folders/9z/bfzgtn696x77lqrpky0c_wv80000gn/T/
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
TERM=xterm-256color
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.ZAyeVsnZjd/Listeners
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=440
TERM_SESSION_ID=47DD351C-3833-4515-9A93-63333DDD163C